# How to get the user id in select Box in controller, i want to delete the selected User

Tags: php, codeigniter-3

**So, here is my View**

```
<select  class="selectpicker" name="cat">
<option label="Select Category">Select to delete</option>
    <?php foreach ($product_cat as $cat){?>
    <option name='catt' value="<?=$cat['pro_cat_id']?>"><?=$cat['category'] ?> </option>
  <?php 

    }?>
  </select>
```

Here is my **controller**
here i want to display the Id but not displaying

```
$id= $this->input->post('catt');
echo $id;
```

Comment: Where is your code to delete the user?

Comment: `cat` != `catt` and is your form `method="post"`?

Comment: The name comes from the `<select>` tag.

Comment: Oh Thanks bro................